# Get medians by single dates

Tags: pandas

First of all, I'm new to Pandas (started this little project 3-4 weeks ago).
I have a data frame full of account movements: ID_Data; ID_Client; Name; Sex; Birthday; Postal Code; Civil State; Coin; Debit; MovementDate.

In this moment, my goal is to get the median by single date like:

1. In 01-01-2019 -> the median of Debits was 20
2. In 01-02-2019 -> the median of Debits was 15
3. In 01-03-2019 -> the median of Debits was 14

I tryed to convert the dates to week numbers, put it in a For and compare each week number to "i", isolating each week to find the median. I don't feel that's the best way and couldn't get any result from it.

```
df['MovementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DataDoMovimento)
df.sort_values('MovementDate')
weekNumber = df['MovementDate'].dt.week
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[df['MovementDate'].dt.week == i+1] is True:
        debitSet = df[df['MovementDate'].dt.week == i+1]
        print(medianPerNumberWeek = sum(debitSet) / len(debitSet))
```

The output was nothing. I'm still a big noob at this, and I'm getting a little stressed out.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

P.S. Sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 1):

```
df['MovementDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DataDoMovimento)
df.groupBy("MovementDate")[["Debit"]].median()
```

This will give you the median for every date under your `MovementDate` column.